# Scrolldown a TableView makes the UIImage background move up

Tags: ios, image, scroll, tableview

Hi here is what I'm trying to do.

I've got a Table View with transparent cell's background.

```
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trans.png"]];
```

And I added to the ViewDidLoad a background image.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

    bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"homelights.png"]];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"";
  }
```

So this works fine, I've got a tableView with transparent cells and a background image. Now the plan is when I scroll the TableView down, the image should react and move up.

Any idea how to trigger the scrolldown? Or where to start?

---

I enabled scrollViewDidScroll;

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
```

Works like a charm, I can read the scroll position, but when I'm trying to animate UIView, by linking the scrollView.contentOffset.y to the UIView "y" position;

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut" context:nil];
    bgView.center = CGPointMake(bgView.center.x, bgView.center.y+scrollOffset);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

So I tried to make the UIView bigger to the original size of the image 640x832 to be able to navigate on it, but doesn't seems to work.

```
 bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 832)];
 bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"homelights.png"]];
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please, meet this guy: [UIColor clearColor];

Answer (score 0):

Your table view is a subclass of `UIScrollView` and your delegate for the table view is also (automatically) a delegate of the scroll view. Implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method and use it to monitor how the table view has changed and move your background view.

Comment: Thanks this is working but I'm getting another problem.- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    printf("Num: %f",scrollOffset);
  
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut" context:nil];
   bgView.center = CGPointMake(bgView.center.x, bgView.center.y+scrollOffset);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    
    //bgView.frame.origin.y = scrollOffset;
    //printf("y background %f",scrollOffset);
    
}

Comment: You don't say what the problem is... You shouldn't need the animation, just change the center. Don't add the scroll offset like that. Use the content offset plus half the view height.

Comment: I tried without the animation, just like this [bgView.center = CGPointMake(bgView.center.x, bgView.frame.size.height/2+scrollOffset);] but nothing happens.

Comment: Scrap `colorWithPatternImage` and use an image view so you can set the size and position properly.

Comment: If I add a ImageView instead, the image shows up at the top of the tableview, like a first cell, not like a background.

Comment: What have you added it as a subview of?

Comment: Of course as a subview! Ok, it's solved now! It's working! Thanks for the support!